# createNewFile() not working and image not being stored

Tags: java, image, spring-mvc

I am trying to save the images in my local machine and its information in the database. But no data is being inserted into the database. The file is being created but their is no content (is of 0 bytes).

I am using hibernate and spring mvc REST API. I am receiving data from an angular 7 app. The program is running on live server but not on my local machine.

On the local server I get this error and response

> POST
>   http://localhost:8080/com_bmis_app_war_exploded/api/product/save/19
>   500 core.js:15724 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of
>   undefined
>       at AppService.push../src/app/app.service.ts.AppService.errorObjToMap
>   (app.service.ts:56)
>       at SafeSubscriber._error (edit-product.component.ts:240)
>       at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:192)...........

This is the response error:
**HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error**

> **Root
>   Cause**
>
> ```
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>     java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:193)
>     java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1763)
>     com.bmis.app.controller.ProductController.saveProduct(ProductController.java:329)
>     com.bmis.app.controller.ProductController.addProduct(ProductController.java:443)......................
> ```

This is my code:

```java
private ResponseEntity saveProduct(Integer id, @Valid @RequestBody Product product, MultipartFile[] images, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    HashMap response = new HashMap();
    boolean success = false;
    List errors = new ArrayList();
    HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
    String message = "";
    Map data = new HashMap();
    Slugify slg = new Slugify();
    String directory = "C:/Users/dellm4700/Documents/images";

    Set<ProductImage> productImages = new HashSet<>();
    for (MultipartFile multipartFile : images) {
        ProductImage productImage = new ProductImage();
        productImage.setSize(multipartFile.getSize());
        productImage.setExtension(multipartFile.getContentType());
        productImage.setActualImageName(new Date().getTime() + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
        productImage.setStandardImageName(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
        productImage.setNameAtFilestore(slg.slugify(productImage.getActualImageName()));
        productImage.setThumbnailImageName("thumb_"+ new Date().getTime() + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
        productImage.setProduct(product);
        productImages.add(productImage);
        File imageFile = new File(directory + "/" + productImage.getActualImageName());
        imageFile.setReadable(true, false);
        imageFile.createNewFile();
        Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = Files.readAttributes(imageFile.toPath(), PosixFileAttributes.class).permissions();
        try {
            multipartFile.transferTo(imageFile);
            perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_READ);
            perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_READ);
            perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_READ);
            Files.setPosixFilePermissions(imageFile.toPath(), perms);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        File thumbFile = new File(directory + "/" + productImage.getThumbnailImageName());
        thumbFile.setReadable(true, false);
        thumbFile.createNewFile();
        Set<PosixFilePermission> thumbperms = Files.readAttributes(thumbFile.toPath(), PosixFileAttributes.class).permissions();
        perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_READ);
        perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_READ);
        perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_READ);
        Files.setPosixFilePermissions(thumbFile.toPath(), perms);

        try {
            Thumbnails.of(directory + "/" + productImage.getActualImageName())
                    .size(200, 200).keepAspectRatio(false)
                    .toFile(thumbFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    productImages.addAll(product.getProductImages());
    product.setProductImages(productImages);

    for (CustomAttribute customAttribute : product.getCustomAttributes()) {
        customAttribute.setProduct(product);
    }

    Claims claims = (Claims) request.getAttribute("claims");

    User user = userService.findById((Integer) claims.get("id"));

    productValidator.validate(product, bindingResult);

    if (id != null) {
        Product sourceProduct = productService.findById(id);
    //  sourceProduct.getPrices().clear();

        if (!(StringUtility.compare(sourceProduct.getName(), product.getName())) && (productService.findByName(product.getName()) != null)) {
            bindingResult.rejectValue("name", null, "Product with same name already exists");
            message = "Fill the form properly";
        } else if (!(StringUtility.compare(sourceProduct.getBarcode(), product.getBarcode())) && (productService.findByBarCode(product.getBarcode()) != null)) {
            message = "Fill the form properly";
            bindingResult.rejectValue("barcode", null, "Product with same barcode already exists");
        }

    //     DaoUtility.copyNonNullProperties(product, sourceProduct);
    //     product = sourceProduct;
    } else {
        if (productService.findByName(product.getName()) != null) {
            message = "Fill the form properly";
            bindingResult.rejectValue("name", null, "Product with same name already exists");
        } else if (productService.findByBarCode(product.getBarcode()) != null) {
            message = "Fill the form properly";
            bindingResult.rejectValue("barcode", null, "Product with same barcode already exists");
        }

    }

    try {
        if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {


            for (Price price : product.getPrices()) {
                price.setProduct(product);
            }

            if (id == null) {
                productService.save(product);

            } else {
                productService.update(product);
            }

            data.put("products", product);
            success = true;
            message = "Product Successfully added";
            httpStatus = HttpStatus.OK;

        } else {
            for (FieldError error : bindingResult.getFieldErrors()) {
                message = "Fill the form properly";
                errors.add(new ErrorMessage(error.getField(), error.getDefaultMessage()));
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        errors.add(new ErrorMessage("error", e.getMessage()));
    }

    response.put("success", success);
    response.put("errors", errors);
    response.put("message", message);
    response.put("data", data);
    return new ResponseEntity(response, httpStatus);
}
```

Comment: 1. `imageFile.setReadable(true, false);` before `imageFile.createNewFile();` is pointless. 2. `imageFile.createNewFile();` before `multipartFile.transferTo(imageFile);` is also pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually was with PosixFilePermission class as this class only works with Linux based operating systems. 
When used readAttributes() method it gave error as Linux has its own methods to get file attributes and windows has its own.